# Reader Writer Lock Implementation

Tags: c++, c++11, locking

I'm practicing to write c++11/14 and I implemented a RW lock. Does everything look ok?

```
class RWLock {
public:
void readLock() {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
    waitingReaders.wait(lock, [this]{!writer && queuedWriters == 0});
    ++readers;
}

void readUnlock() {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
    --readers;
    if (readers == 0 && queuedWriters > 0) {
        lock.unlock();
        waitingWriters.notify_one();
    }
}

void writeLock() {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
    ++queuedWriters;
    waitingWriters.wait(lock, [this]{!writer && readers == 0});
    --queuedWriters;
    writer = true;
}

void writeUnlock() {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex);

    if(queuedWriters > 0) {
        lock.unlock();
        waitingWriters.notify_one();
    } else {
        writer = false;
        lock.unlock();
        waitingReaders.notify_all();
    }
}

private:
std::mutex mutex;
std::condition_variable waitingReaders;
std::condition_variable waitingWriters;

int readers = 0;
int queuedWriters = 0;
bool writer = false;    
};
```

In particular:
Do I really need to take a lock in my `WriteUnlock()` method? It looks like all I'm doing is unlock right away.

And is it recommended to perform a `lock.unlock()` before I do a `notify_one` or a `notify_all` ?

Does performing a `condition_variable.wait(lock, lambda)` where the lambda is `true` cause a performance loss? Like potentially in the `readLock()` method

Answer (score 2):

> Do I really need to take a lock in my `WriteUnlock()` method? It looks like all I'm doing is unlock right away.

YES, you need the lock, because you are accessing `queuedWriters` and you need to make sure nobody changes it (by calling `writeLock`) before you notify readers or writers based on the check. You could have seen `queuedWriters` being zero, therefore notifying readers, but some writer could get sleeping in the meantime and never get woken.

> And is it recommended to perform a `lock.unlock()` before I do a `notify_one` or a `notify_all`?

Unlock before, because the thread being woken would immediatelly try to hold the lock, thus being blocked again (to be woken for second time when you unlock).

> Does performing a `condition_variable.wait(lock, lambda)` where the lambda is true cause a performance loss?

It is same as `while (!pred()) wait(lck);`
What else could you do? It checks first, so, would not wait if the condition is true.

Comment: I have also always wondered if you need to `unlock()` before a `notify*()`. But I have never found a reference with this recommendation (for or against). If you have a reference for this I would love to read it. Currently I am not convinced by your logic; just because you notify the conditional does not mean that anything happens immediately. Note: I am not saying it is bad advice (it seems logical and does not seem to break things) but I would love to read from an authoritative reference.

Comment: @MartinYork https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17101922/do-i-have-to-acquire-lock-before-calling-condition-variable-notify-one